# using a4j:support for oncomplete

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using h:commandButton instead of a4j:commandButton cause I am trying to do the file upload. However, h:commandButton doesn't have the oncomplete function, which I need. Note that `<f:ajax>` tag doesn't work (I believe we use jsf-1 not 2)

```
<h:commandButton id="button" action="#{controller.method}" onclick=" this.disabled=true " ... >
    <a4j:support event="onclick" oncomplete="document.getElementById('button').disabled=false" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance

Comment: RichFaces has a fileUpload component, what do you need the button for? Or a better question would be why do you need to disable the button? (It wouldn't work the way you're trying to do it.)

Comment: @Makhiel, thanks for checking this. I think we want to disable the button is to avoid the customer double click.

Answer (score 0):

`<h:commandButton>` performs a full submit (ie. not an ajax request) so you cannot fire javascript after because the page is reloaded

If you want to disable the button after clicking use the `onclick` or `ondblclick` attributes